# How to reliably detect if a python docstring is in rest?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I'm developing a docstring viewer and so I would like to properly convert any docstring to good looking html.

Docstrings in most of the standard libraries are not in [reST](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html), but that's not the case for scientific libraries, which have adopted for the most part the [numpydoc](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpydoc/0.4) standard.

So I would like to reliably detect whether a docstring is in reST or not, in order to pass it to different renders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since ReST is a format that tries to look as much as possible like readable plain text, there is no reliable way to detect if any piece of text is using ReST, let alone something as small as a docstring.

I'd say you should just try and render it as ReST and give the end-user the option to switch that off again.

Comment: maybe he could try it the other way around. testing if there are no reST-violations and then assuming it's at least reST conform. (e.g.: no html tags or @param constructs...)

Comment: Not the kind answer I was waiting for :) but you are right. I'll try to render docstrings from the standard library as unformatted html and the ones coming from scientific libraries with Sphinx. But I'll also give users an easy option to switch from one to the other.